# Compress CVSampleBuffer in BrodcastExtension

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, telegram, replaykit

I have an app that broadcasts the screen of the device. I am using [OpenTok](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/tree/main/Broadcast-Ext) library to send the frames. Their library does not handle the compressing process so every time I send a frame using this code to consume Buffer:

`self.videoCaptureConsumer?.consumeImageBuffer(pixelBuffer,                                                      orientation:sample.orientation.openTokOrientation,timestamp:CMSampleBufferGetPresentatioTimeStamp(sample) ,metadata:nil)`

the Broadcast extension crashes because of the memory limitation(50MB).

I have been searching in SO as well as repos in GitHub finally I ended up using a CPU image processing using Accelerate. I created an extension of CVPixelBuffer to resize the buffer. Here is the [extension](https://gist.github.com/mehmetbaykar/779ff89b9dfa524c1cfb94d5d7dcda7c)

I can resize the CVPixelBuffer and then send the new buffer to the OpenTok library. But the problem is since it is done by CPU, on iPhones X and below, the broadcast extension is stopped by the high CPU usage by the system.

So, I thought I have to find a way to compress-resize the buffer in a faster and memory-safer way with GPU acceleration.

Then I ended up checking Telegram's iOS app. I discovered the [Telegram`s Broadcast Extension](https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/Telegram-iOS/blob/master/Telegram/BroadcastUpload/BroadcastUploadExtension.swift) which actually works like a charm and it is what I need but I lack information on how it works since it uses C libraries.

**My question is how I can compress-resize the CVPixelBuffer in a similar way that Telegram does but at least written with Swift language without passing memory limit and using GPU acceleration?**